# Spring Boot Kafka Batch DefaultErrorHandler does not log errors

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In a Spring boot kafka batch consumer, I want continue processing if an error occurs and log a warning.

I've added a `DefaultErrorHandler` with an Exponential backoff. I was expecting any errors in the listen method to be logged by the `DefaultErrorHandler`.

Does `DefaultErrorHandler` no longer work that way in batch mode? What am I doing wrong to get the desired result. See the code below for a minimal example:

VERSIONS:

- spring-kafka 2.9.12
- spring-boot-starter 2.7.15

MINIMAL EXAMPLE: (in a SpringBootApplication)

```
    val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyApplication::class.java)
    val processor = MyProcessor()


    fun parseKafkaEvent(it: ConsumerRecord<String, String>) = try {
        objectMapper.readValue(it.value()) as MyMappedEvent
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        logger.warn("Could not parse event", e)
        null
    }

    @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["my-topic"],
        groupId = "my-group-id",
        batch = "true"
    )
    fun listen(records: ConsumerRecords<String, String>) {
        val events = records
            .asSequence()
            .map {
                parseKafkaEvent(it)
            }.toList()
        processor.process(events)
    }

    @Configuration
    class KafkaConfiguration {
       @Bean
        fun errorHandler(): DefaultErrorHandler = DefaultErrorHandler(ExponentialBackOff())
            .apply { setLogLevel(KafkaException.Level.WARN) }
    }
```

I tried to switch to a DefautErrorHandler with a ConsumerRecordRecoverer and add a not retryableException which issues the log, but stops the batch procesing as well.

```
    @Bean
    fun errorHandler(): CommonErrorHandler {
        val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("KafkaErrorHandler")
        val eh = DefaultErrorHandler(
            { _: ConsumerRecord<*, *>?, ex: Exception? -> logger.warn(ex?.message) },
            ExponentialBackOff()
        ).apply { setLogLevel(WARN) }
        eh.addNotRetryableExceptions(Exception::class.java)
        return eh
    }
```

Comment: It appears you also opened an issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2818 - you don't have to report a problem in multiple places; it wastes your time and ours.

Comment: Well if I was 100% sure it is not an error on my side, the github issue would be just fine. But I am not. that is why I posted it here, too.

Comment: So just post here then, initially.